# Android navigation drawer - remove the horizontal bars separating each item

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to remove or set transparent the horizontal bars separating each item in the navigation drawer menu.

Here is a screenshot from my app:

[image]

I want to remove or set same color as background color or set as transparent those horizontal grey bars.

Here's my XML code:

custom_drawer_item.xml

```
<.?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<.RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#edf7f2" 
android:divider="@android:color/transparent">

<!-- Accounts -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/spinnerLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/drawerSpinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent">

    <!-- Representing the category title in the navigation drawer -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/drawerTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#96ca2d"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp" 
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent">
    </View>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/itemLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="50dp" 
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <!-- Menu Items -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_itemName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#4bb5c1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
        />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" 
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent">
    </View>
</LinearLayout>

<./RelativeLayout>
```

drawer_list_item.xml

```
<.TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
android:textColor="#4bb5c1" 
android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
/>
```

drawer_layout.xml

```
<.?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<.RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator" 
android:divider="@android:color/transparent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:contentDescription="descri imagem"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" />

<./RelativeLayout>
```

PS; Don't mind the `.` (dot) in the xml code, it's there just to enforce SO to show those lines otherwise for some reason those lines wouldn't be shown in my question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your layout of activity that contains navigation drawer in the listview put these lines

```
android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

try to customize your items' background by setting a custom drawable:

1/ create a little file in your res/drawable : white_empty_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

</shape>
```

2/ in your item's layout set this drawable as background.

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp" 
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent">
</View>
```

from your xml
and then try it, must work

Comment: I removed that view but the horizontal bars are still present

Comment: try it after removing this 
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"  from your linearlayouts